# Local variable declaration in /etc/init.d/functions

Tags: bash

On RHEL, the `daemon()` function in /etc/init.d/functions is defined as follows:

```
daemon() {
    # Test syntax.
    local gotbase= force= nicelevel corelimit
    local pid base= user= nice= bg= pid_file=
    local cgroup=
    nicelevel=0
    ... and so on ...
```

I'm trying to understand why some of the local variables are defined with an equals sign and some others not. What's happening here? Is this multiple declaration and assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local varname
```

declares a local variable, but doesn't initialize it with any value.

```
local varname=value
```

declares a local variable, and also initializes it to `value`. You can initialize it to an empty string by providing an empty `value`, as in

```
local varname=
```

So in your example, `pid` is declared but not initialized, while `base` is declared and initialized to an empty string.

For most purposes there's not much difference between an unset variable and having an empty string as the value. But some of the parameter expansion operators can distinguish them. E.g.

```
${varname:-default}
```

will expand to `default` if `varname` is unset or empty, but

```
${varname-default}
```

will expand to `default` only if `varname` is unset. So if you use

```
${base-default}
```

it will expand to the empty string, not `default`.